# How to execute cutom code after validation get success with Page_ClientValidate

Tags: asp.net, validation

**I have two types of filed one is Required and Other is Not Required.**

If user will press submit button then i call a function where i have setup logic for checking

1. Required Field Validation (if user would enter all the details in required file then)

2. Check for Not Required Field (then i have to prompt user for You have not entered following details ... Do you want to fill these details? Yes | No)

3. If i press Yes then page should not submit

4. else page should submit

i have done all the thing but it is not working, following are my code snippet

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CheckEmptyField() {
            var isPageValid;
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                isPageValid = Page_ClientValidate();
                if (isPageValid) {
                    var elementNotRequired = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
                    var strvalidationMessage = "<h5>You haven’t entered the following columns:</h5><br/><ul>";
                    for (var ele = 0; elementNotRequired.length; ele++) {
                        if (elementNotRequired[ele].className == 'NotRequired') {
                            strvalidationMessage += "<li>" + elementNotRequired[ele].innerText + "</li>";
                        }
                    }
                    strvalidationMessage += "</ul><br/> <h6>Do you want to enter these details?</h6>";
                    isPageValid = confirm(strvalidationMessage);
                }
            }
            return isPageValid;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="650px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Following fields are <b>Required!</b>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Following fields are <b>Not Required!</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                        ErrorMessage="First Name is required" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Education
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEducation"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span class="NotRequired">Education</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Last Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
                        ErrorMessage="Last Name is required" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Company Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyName"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span class="NotRequired">Company Name</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAge"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge"
                        ErrorMessage="Age is required" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return CheckEmptyField();" />
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: nope, i think i had written correct code but why it is not working?

Comment: You mean YES and page SHOULD submit right?

Comment: No, it is not working...

Comment: If the dialog is asking them if they want to fill in missing information, and cancel the post back when they click YES, then you should exit and return at the confirm prompt, like this: return !comfirm('...');

Comment: but in my case the the control never goes in following line: **isPageValid = confirm(strvalidationMessage);**

Comment: @JamesJohnson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2511/discussion-between-imdadhusen-and-james-johnson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your "for" loop. Change the start of your loop to the following:

```
for ( var ele = 0; ele < elementNotRequired.length; ele++ )
```

With this change and the way you have your function logic, the user will get the confirm prompt and if the user clicks "Cancel", the page will not post back.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a revised version of your js method on submit of the form, which should occur after the validations have fired. Revise your js to cancel the submission if the user wants to answer the non-required values.

Comment: but how to cancel form submission?

Comment: Just return false in the onsubmit client event

Comment: You'll need to also place a return statement on the submit statement.

Comment: onsubmit = "return CheckEmptyField();" If you want the submission to go through if the user answers OK to the confirm prompt, then return isPageValid from your function. If you want your submission to be canceled if the user answers OK, then return !isPageValid.

Comment: I have already written logic for returning True or False but it couldn't work!